# changing text in a Jabel

Tags: java, jlabel

I am trying to add a few extras to a project to get an understanding of gui interfaces.
I am building an alarm panel in java and I just wanted to make the text change during the various states of activation, i.e. go from arming to armed and disarming to disarmed.

I tried using the `Thread.sleep` method but this only delays the amount of time it takes for my text to appear on screen.
Can you advise the direction I need to look up. Below is a section  I am working on but I have the full code available if its required.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    else if(e.getSource() == disarm){
    dPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    adPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    screen.setText("Disarming");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {                                         
       e1.printStackTrace();
       }
 screen.setText("Disarmed");
```

Comment: we dont all start to learn as pro's . This is why i ask some experienced people for direction.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `Thread.sleep` *ever* in Swing, it blocks the `EDT` — Use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead.

Comment: great. I never used threads before but i will research the timers now... Thanks to gd1 also

Comment: +1 for suggestion the Swing Timer (as oppose to the other answer which just suggests a Timer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with Thread.sleep() you are blocking the GUI thread, and you shall **never** do that. Use a timer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. If you do need a timer, use one:
[Swing Timer example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Maybe you could try to explain your problem in other way for making it more understandable.

Comment: -1, the Swing Timer suggestion was made 7 minutes earlier. No need to clutter the forum with duplicate suggestions.

Comment: Oh sorry you're right! I should shoot myself! Sure that by my fault a little kitten died! XD